# My background image won't recognize height property

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the height 100% for the background image in this page, but it doesn't seem to be working. I have tried so many different methods and nothings seems to work.

```
.signupbackground {
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
z-index: 0;
}
```

The code right looks like this. I also tried this:

```
.signupbackground {
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
z-index: 0;
}
```

My body and html already have the 100% height property.

```
body, html {
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
background: #efefef;
color: black;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Here is the html

```
<body>

<!-- Loader -->
<div class="fh5co-loader"></div>

<div id="fh5co-page">
    <section id="fh5co-header">
        <div class="container">
            <nav role="navigation">
            <h1 id="fh5co-logo"><a href="../index.php"><img id="logo01" src="../img/spredtlogo.png"></a></h1>
                <ul class="pull-right right-menu">
                    <li class="fh5co-cta-btn1"><a href="login.php">Log in</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="no-js-fullheight1" data-next="yes">
    </section>

    <!-- END #fh5co-hero -->
    <div class="signupbackground" style="background-image: url(../img/blur.jpg)">
       <div class="container">

    <div class="memberform">
<div id="msg"></div>
        <h3>Create a new account</h3>
        <h4>Take full advantage of all the new features</h4>

                <input type="text" id="first" placeholder="First Name">
                <input type="text" id="last" placeholder="Last Name">
                <div id="error_1"></div>
                <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                <div id="error_2"></div>
                <input type="text" id="number" placeholder="Phone number">
                <input type="text" id="uid" placeholder="Username">
                <div id="error_3"></div>
                <input type="password" id="pwd" placeholder="Password">
                <div id="error_4"></div>
                <button class="signup-button" onclick="signup()">Create Account</button>

        <p>By choosing "Create Account" you are accepting to the <a href="termsofuse.php">terms and conditions.</a></p>
    </div>
        </div>
      </div>

<section id="secondary-footer">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="footer-element">
            <ul>
                <li>&copy; 2017 Spredt</li>
                <li><a href="../termsofuse.php">Terms of use</a></li>
                <li><a href="../jobs.php">Careers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
        <!-- END #fh5co-footer -->
    </div>
    <!-- END #fh5co-page -->


    </body>
</html>
```

But it still looks like this

I want to get rid of the ugly space that is there. Another thing I read is to add height to a parent div, I did that and it made the image bigger but the space was still there. Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: include your html, we don't know what to do without a template

Comment: Already added it, sorry

Comment: Check applied css with dev tools on Chrome or Firefox. May be size is limited by an inherited style.

Comment: You could easily test if it's an inherited override by adding the "!important" annotation. I wouldn't recommend leaving it this way however (it's not a fix) as it will likely cause you more problems down the road if left on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the division itself does not have an adjustable height is what causes the background image to go bananas. It's true that the `<html>` and `<body>` tags should be 100% in height, but that's not enough since the image is not following those tags' rules, but the division's instead. Therefore, use the CSS `calc()` function.

Also, `background-attachment: fixed;` is not necessary, but `background-position: center;` will be very much needed.

```
.signupbackground {
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center;
     z-index: 0;
     height: calc(100vh - /* header height + footer height in px */); // example: height: calc(100vh - 90px);
}
```